# Academic journals dedicated to quantum algorithms

Tags: resource-request, research

Are there, any journals out there that have been steadily publishing, or are dedicated to, research on existing or new and innovative quantum *algorithms*? Generalist titles are fine, but they can also be field-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following are a few insightful journals on quantum information, computation and algorithms.

- [Quantum Journal](https://quantum-journal.org/)
- [Quantum Information and Computation](http://www.rintonpress.com/journals/qic/index.html)
- [Journal of Quantum Computing](https://www.techscience.com/journal/jqc)

Comment: +1 for Quantum Journal (https://quantum-journal.org/), it’s relatively new but is publishing very high quality papers.